# adding js function vars to function call after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add this button with js

```
'<td><button  id="'+value['itemId']+'" onclick="toggle_button_functunality("item",this.id);">Edit</button></td>' +
```

Problem is: I cant send the string Item to toggle_button_functunality(item,elementId)
Keep getting syntax errors, any ideas?

Comment: remove doublt quotes from item..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape inner quotes.

Use

```
'<td><button onclick="toggle_button_functunality(\'item\',this.id);">Edit</button></td>'
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/5nqqC/1/)

Comment: what this do actually ``\'``??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad When the string will be added as HTML, it will be converted to `toggle_button_functunality('item',this.id);` heres demo http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/5nqqC/1/

Comment: @Ehsan it is called escaping the quots.